# Function That Parses Array Is Always Returning "True"

Tags: php, arrays, shopify

I'm building a Shopify site for a client, and we're working with an app (Bespoke Shipping) that allows you to write PHP code to manipulate variables delivered into a function. I've got a test using a foreach loop that I'm using to check whether or not an order is being shipped to a state in the lower 48 U.S. states. This test is always returning "true", when it should only be returning "true" when the array of the lower 48 state abbreviations isn't matched with the state it's being delivered to. Here's my code:

```
$usr_province = $DATA['destination']['province'];

$is_lower_48 = false;
$lower_48 = array('AL', 'AZ', 'AR', 'CA', 'CO', 'CT', 'DE', 'FL', 'GA', 'ID', 'IL', 'IN', 'IA', 'KS', 'KY', 'LA', 'ME', 'MD', 'MA', 'MI', 'MN', 'MS', 'MO', 'MT', 'NE', 'NV', 'NH', 'NJ', 'NM', 'NY', 'NC', 'ND', 'OH', 'OK', 'OR', 'PA', 'RI', 'SC', 'SD', 'TN', 'TX', 'UT', 'VT', 'VA', 'WA', 'WV', 'WI', 'WY');

foreach ($lower_48 as $m) {
    if ($usr_province == $m) {
        $is_lower_48 = true;
    }
}

if (($DATA['destination']['country'] == 'US') && ($is_lower_48 == true)) {
    /* apply the rules for lower 48 U.S. shipping */
} elseif (($DATA['destination']['country'] == 'US') && ($is_lower_48 == false))  { /* If the destination country is in the US and NOT in the lower 48 states */
    /* apply the rules for non-contiguous U.S. shipping */
}
```

Comment: so if i am reading right `$is_lower_48 = true;` should only occur when `$usr_province` isn't in the array `$lower_48`, correct?

Comment: dont loop: `if(in_array($usr_province,$lower_48))`, tweak case if needed

Comment: Memor-X - the opposite. $is_lower_48 should be set to true if the $lower_48 array contains $usr_province.

Comment: What is the test data that it fails for?

Comment: samgak- It's a little odd. Basically, there's a custom shipping option in Shopify that works with the app I'm using. If test data for the lower 48 fails and the country is still the U.S., it should show up in that custom shipping option. I know it's evaluating to "true" every time because the code turns up in the shipping area when I flip the if statements.

Comment: What I mean is, what is the literal string for the state that is not working? Can you confirm that it has no trailing spaces, is in the exact format you expect (a two letter code) and so on

Comment: Nope. The solution below worked for me though. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use in_array(in array) function to check the value present inside the array

```
$usr_province = $DATA['destination']['province'];

$is_lower_48 = false;
$lower_48 = array('AL', 'AZ', 'AR', 'CA', 'CO', 'CT', 'DE', 'FL', 'GA', 'ID', 'IL', 'IN', 'IA', 'KS', 'KY', 'LA', 'ME', 'MD', 'MA', 'MI', 'MN', 'MS', 'MO', 'MT', 'NE', 'NV', 'NH', 'NJ', 'NM', 'NY', 'NC', 'ND', 'OH', 'OK', 'OR', 'PA', 'RI', 'SC', 'SD', 'TN', 'TX', 'UT', 'VT', 'VA', 'WA', 'WV', 'WI', 'WY');

if(in_array($usr_province, $lower_48)) {
    $is_lower_48 = true;
}


if (($DATA['destination']['country'] == 'US') && ($is_lower_48 == true)) {
    /* apply the rules for lower 48 U.S. shipping */
} elseif (($DATA['destination']['country'] == 'US') && ($is_lower_48 == false))  { /* If the destination country is in the US and NOT in the lower 48 states */
    /* apply the rules for non-contiguous U.S. shipping */
}
```